# Stata: date comparison in double

Tags: stata

I'm trying to divide the data by a certain datetime.

[image]

I've created `e_time`from what was originally  a string  `"2019-10-15 20:33:04"` for example.

To obtain all the information from the string containing h:m:s, I uses the following command to create a `double`

```
gen double e_time = clock(event_timestamp, "YMDhms")
```

Now  I get the result I want from `format e_time %tc` (human readable),
I want to `generate` a new variable anything that is greater than 2019-10-15 as 1 and anything less than that as 0 .

I've tried

```
// 1 

gen new_d = 0 if e_time < "1.887e+12"
replace new_d = 1 if e_time >= "1.887e+12"

// 2 

gen new_d = 0 if e_time < "2019-10-15"
replace new_d = 1 if e_time > "2019-10-15"
```

However, I get an error message  `type mismatch`.

I tried converting a string `"2019-10-15"` to `double \`to check if 1.887e+12 really meant 2019-10-15 using `display`, but I'm not sure how the command really works here.

Anyhow I tried

```
// 3 

di clock("2019-10-15", "YMDhms")
```

but it didn't work.

Can anyone give advice on comparing dates that are in a `double` format properly?

Comment: It's not hard to learn how to display code here. Indent 4 spaces for lines of code; use backticks for mentions of code. (Look at the edits for example.)

Comment: The word "format" is overloaded in computing, which isn't your fault, but note that in Stata `double` is a variable or storage type and **not** a display format. An expression "double format" can be translated mentally, but using Stata terminology in a Stata question is always the best idea.

Comment: @NickCox thank you very much for the clarification. Also the references you've suggested for getting rid of redundant generate replace is extremely helpful! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is a little hard to follow (a reproducible data example would help a lot) but the error `type mismatch` is because `e_time` is numeric, and `"2019-10-15"` is a string.

I suggest the following:

```
clear

input str20 datetime
"2019-10-14 20:33:04"
"2019-10-16 20:33:04"
end

* Keep first 10 characters
gen date = substr(datetime,1,10)

* Check that all strings are 10 characters
assert length(date) == 10

* Convert from string to numeric date variable
gen m = substr(date,6,2)
gen d = substr(date,9,2)
gen y = substr(date,1,4)

destring m d y, replace

gen newdate = mdy(m,d,y)
format newdate %d

gen wanted = newdate >= mdy(10,15,2019) & !missing(newdate)

drop date m d y

list

     +------------------------------------------+
     |            datetime     newdate   wanted |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. | 2019-10-14 20:33:04   14oct2019        0 |
  2. | 2019-10-16 20:33:04   16oct2019        1 |
     +------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice! However, I need to keep the h:m:s part specifically within the result datetime and then compare it. It seems like current datetime is ignoring the h:m:s part..

Comment: input str20 datetime
"2019-10-14 20:33:04"
"2019-10-14 20:33:04"

gen double date = clock(datetime, "YMDhms")

gen group = 0 if date  <  "2019-10-15"
replace group =1 if date > "2019-10-15" 

is exactly what I wanted to do, but as you can see I've created a date object as double, which is causing type mismatch problem.. srry if I've confused you

Comment: Helpful as always. I've edited out the unnecessary `generate replace` two-step for an indicator variable. Doing it in one line is  explained in various places, such as https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/ and https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099

Comment: @LeeVincent, yes that won't work because you're comparing a numeric variable to a string. Did you try the solution in my answer? The `mdy()` function in the last `generate` statement is the key. And thank you Nick, very handy to know. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you both @ Nick Cox and @Cybernike!
1) @ Nick, I wasn't actually aware of doing it with one line, but thanks to your references, now I see that generate replace two-step process is unnecessary. Thank you. 

2) @Cybernike yes I did, and specifically it worked for entire dataset as well.
I didn't  really know what substr() could do, so it took me a while to actually comprehend what happened when I ran the code. But now I do!

I'm pretty new to Stata, and I've actually learned a lot from this thread.

Thank you all for sharing your knowledge:)